# transfer data from one form dataGridView to another form TextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have `dataGridView` in `Form1` and I need to transfer the data that in selected row to another form `text box`.
When  someone clicks on a row and then clicks on update button...

`FORM1`
[image: Form1]

the following screen will occur with the referenced data.

`AddUpdateForm`
[image]
The following code is for the `UPDATE` button

```
 private void updateBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {

             AddUpdateForm addUpdate = new AddUpdateForm();
             addUpdate.ShowDialog();
 }
```

This code is for the click event on `dataGridViewPRoducts`

```
   private void dataGridViewProducts_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            AddUpdateForm addUpdate = new AddUpdateForm();
            Products pro = new Products();
            if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
            {
                DataGridViewRow row = dataGridViewProducts.Rows[e.RowIndex];
                pro.Name = row.Cells["name"].Value.ToString();
                pro.Brand = row.Cells["brand"].Value.ToString();
                pro.Item_Price = Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells["item_price"].Value.ToString());
                pro.StokType =row.Cells["stock_type"].Value.ToString();
                pro.Stock_Amount = Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells["stock_amount"].Value.ToString());
                textBox1.Text = row.Cells["name"].Value.ToString();
            }
```

Actually I know i need to return the `pro` object to the `UPDATE button`. However, I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Move the code in the `CellContentClick` event to the `updateBtn_Click` event. Use the grids `CurrentRow` property to create the `Products` `pro` object. Then pass the `pro` object to the `AddUpdateForm`. Something like… `AddUpdateForm addUpdate = new AddUpdateForm(pro);`. There are other ways to do this and there should be plenty of examples with a google search.

Comment: There are two problems to do what you said. First one, `AddUpdateForm` does not except a `pro` object . The second one is when I move the code, I need a `DataGridViewCellEventArgs` object which I have a `EventArgs` in `updateBtn_Click`. Can you post an answer or link a solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your comment about the two problems…

> *”First one, AddUpdateForm does not except a pro object.”*

This is true, and my comment implied that you should create a constructor that "does" accept a pro object. Then the form can access the passed in `Products` object. Something like…

```
private Products currentProduct;

public AddUpdateForm(Products passedInProduct) {
  currentProduct = passedInProduct;
  InitializeComponent();
}

private void AddUpdateForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  // here you can use the passed in Products object called currentProduct
}
```

Your second Comment…

> *”The second one is when I move the code, I need a DataGridViewCellEventArgs object which I have a EventArgs in
> updateBtn_Click.”*

This is not true. You do not need the `DataGridViewCellEventArgs` object. In its current state, by setting the `pro` object in the grids `CellContentClick` event means that ONLY if the user “clicks” on a cell then the `pro` object gets set… what if the user pressed the down arrow instead of clicking? If the user never clicks a cell, `pro` will be null.

You want to grab the currently “selected” row no matter how the user “selected" it. So it makes no sense to grab this row until the user presses the “update” button. Then we simply select the grids `CurrentRow`… i.e. … the girds currently selected row.

Therefore, the update button click event may look something like…

```
private void updateBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  DataGridViewRow row = dataGridViewReport.CurrentRow;
  Products pro = new Products {
    Name = row.Cells["name"].Value.ToString(),
    Brand = row.Cells["brand"].Value.ToString(),
    Item_Price = Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells["item_price"].Value.ToString()),
    StokType = row.Cells["StokType"].Value.ToString(),
    Stock_Amount = Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells["Stock_Amount"].Value.ToString())
  };
  AddUpdateForm addUpdate = new AddUpdateForm(pro);
  addUpdate.ShowDialog();
}
```

Or if the grids data source is a `List<Products>` then instead of grabbing the values from the individual cells, you could just get the `DataBoundItem` from the row and cast it to a `Products` object like...

```
Products pro = (Products)dataGridViewReport.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem;
```

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Thanks a lot it works perfectly. I appriciate it.